# How to open a Primefaces Tab panel when clicked?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Is this possible to open Tab Panel when clicked on the Tab header only? So here is the detail requirement if you will check Linkdin they have three button or Tab

1. Share an Update
2. Upload a Photo
3. Write an article

If user will click Share an Update it will open a Panel along with button i want same thing can be achieve with Tabs ? If yes how can someone please guide me?

Comment: what do you mean by open , does it mean appear ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight its something like Linkdin where when you login it show 3 option ->Share an Update,Upload a Photo,Write an article and when you click then only open a panel

Comment: the only thing that make something appear and disappear is `rendred` but it's really hard to work with it, the solution is to use `block UI` what do you thnik about it ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight `rendred` i am aware about it but that will not solve my problem i was looking something like linkdin .when you click panel will appear with button look like tab only. why you mentioned `block ui` i am not able to understand that

Comment: please look to this link http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml

Comment: @YagamiLight I am aware about this feature how it will helpful for my requirment

Comment: Your question is 100% unclear... What is the other way you can open a tab?

Comment: @Kukeltje Read now may be now it could clear.

Comment: If you want that specific behavior implemented with "TabView" component you can do it by modifying the component and the meaning of the "TabView". That is more a "TabMenu" implementation or just a "commandButton" one.